# Chapter heading memoir: Line space, page number position, section font

Tags: fonts, spacing, header-footer, memoir, page-numbering

1) Main question: How do I reduce the line space in the chapter heading? It seems to use that

`\setSingleSpace{1.3}
    \SingleSpacing`

I would like the chapter header to be single spaced with 1.0. However, this then applies to the whole document.

2) How do I make the page number aligned with either the first or the second line in the header? At the moment it is somewhere in between.

3) How do I change the section font in the header to `\textsc`? Only in the header, not in the document text.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,english,reqno, twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}[2011/08/13]
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    \numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage[american, german]{babel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{delarray}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{emptypage}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{floatpag}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[unicode=true, hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[outer=5cm, inner=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\usepackage[sort, numbers, authoryear, comma]{natbib}
%\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{footmisc}
% \usepackage{floatrow}\cite
%\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{a4wide}
%\usepackage{endfloat}
%\usepackage{palatino}
%\usepackage{pslatex}
%\usepackage{scalefnt}
%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{ulem}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setSingleSpace{1.3}
\SingleSpacing

\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setSingleSpace{1.3}
\SingleSpacing

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{4cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{4cm}

\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
 \setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}
 \nouppercaseheads
%\pagestyle{headings}

\checkandfixthelayout

\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.15cm}

\checkandfixthelayout

\setSingleSpace{1.3}
\SingleSpacing
\setFloatSpacing{1.1}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\chapter[How do I reduce chapter heading line space? How do I reduce chapter heading line space?]{How do I reduce chapter heading line space? How do I reduce chapter heading line space?}
\markboth{\small {\textsc{\thechapter. How do I reduce chapter heading line space? How do I reduce chapter heading line space?}}}{}

\section{How to change this font?}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

EDIT: 1) and 2) are solved by removing the `scrlayer-scrpage` package. As requested, the MWE is then:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,english,reqno, twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}[2011/08/13]
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    \numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage[american, german]{babel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{delarray}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{emptypage}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{floatpag}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[unicode=true, hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[outer=5cm, inner=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\usepackage[sort, numbers, authoryear, comma]{natbib}
%\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{footmisc}
% \usepackage{floatrow}\cite
%\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{a4wide}
%\usepackage{endfloat}
%\usepackage{palatino}
%\usepackage{pslatex}
%\usepackage{scalefnt}
%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{ulem}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setSingleSpace{1.3}
\SingleSpacing

\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setSingleSpace{1.3}
\SingleSpacing

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{4cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{4cm}

\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
 \setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}
 \nouppercaseheads
%\pagestyle{headings}

\checkandfixthelayout

\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.15cm}

\checkandfixthelayout

\setSingleSpace{1.3}
\SingleSpacing
\setFloatSpacing{1.1}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\chapter[How do I reduce chapter heading line space? How do I reduce chapter heading line space?]{How do I reduce chapter heading line space? How do I reduce chapter heading line space?}
\markboth{\small {\textsc{\thechapter. How do I reduce chapter heading line space? How do I reduce chapter heading line space?}}}{}

\section{How to change this font?}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Updated the tags.

Answer (score 3):

An answer to two of your questions.

```
...
\setSingleSpace{1} % normal space between lines
\SingleSpacing
\chapter[How do ...]{How do I reduce chapter heading line space? How do I ...}
\setSingleSpace{1.3} % more space between lines
\SingleSpacing

\setsecheadstyle{\large\scshape\raggedright} % change section head font
\section{How to change this font?}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

I don't know about the page header and number but if the header is a single line, which it normally is, then the page number is aligned with that line.

Running you MWE produced various warnings. It is not a good idea to use the `setspace`, `titlesec`, or `scrlayer-scrpage` packages with `memoir`. You used the `\setSingleSpacing \SingleSpacing` macro pairs several times before the final effective pairing.

Comment: I can manage 1) by going single-spaced everywhere which is fine with me. 2) I have solved by getting rid of `scrlayer-scrpage`. 3) To be more precise: I want to have the font in the header to be `scshape` everywhere. The `\setsecheadstyle` suggestion does not do that for me as it seems.

Comment: @360McTwist then please add the new MWE to your question, and please remove irrelevant packages from it as well.

Comment: Update: Noticed only removing `scrlayer-scrpage` solves 1) and 2). Still wondering about 3) though.

Comment: @360McTwist I am confused. You originally wanted the chapter heading single spaced while the rest remained double spaced. You asked how to change the font of `section` but now you say that what I provided did not do that, but it did what you requested.

Comment: @PeterWilson yes, removing `scrlayer-scrpage` made the chapter heading single-spaced and aligned the page number. The section font in the chapter heading was changed by the suggestion of @daleif. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For (3)

```
\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{}{\small\scshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\small\scshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}

\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{headings}
```

This makes all the headers scshape